# Material Based Outline EEVEE

Tags: texturing, materials, npr

Hey quick question is there a way to make mesh outline using only material nodes (no inverted hull method).

Comment: Not good ones.  You could use the dot product of the normal with incoming to mix with outline color; mix when the dot product is, say, <0.05.  This won't look good on a low poly mesh, but as your vertex count approaches infinity, on something smooth shaded, it will look fine.

Comment: There's video tutorial on how to do it.
here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMDKuWa5OMo